# Solve: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve

Tags: equation-solving

So, my problem looks fairly simple, but I can't find the solution whatsoever. I am guessing it has to do with the domain since the result is a Napierian log equation.

So, this is what I am trying to solve:

```
(Pe (θ2 λ ψ1 + ψ2 - E^(1/2 Pe (-L ψ2 + L (ψ2 + ψ3))) θ2 ψ2 - ψ3 + E^(1/2 Pe (-L ψ3 + L (ψ2 + ψ3))) θ2 ψ3))/λ == 0
```

This is what I have tried to use:

```
Simplify[Solve[eq1, L, Reals]]
```

Unfortunately, I keep receiving the following message:

Solve: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.

The equation can be done by hand really simply, so I know the result, but I need Mathematica to calculate it for me. Can anyone help me with this issue?

All the best,

Comment: Your equation makes no sense as written.

Comment: To add to the comment by @1729taxi you have ONE equation and nobody knows how many unknowns. When you say that you can easily solve it by hand, how do you mean that? Could you provide what you did by hand so we can get a better feeling about what's going on?

Comment: `(inst1 = FindInstance[eq1, {L, Pe, \[Theta]2, \[Lambda], \[Psi]1, \[Psi]2, \[Psi]3}, Reals][[1]]) // N` or `(inst2 = FindInstance[eq1, {L, Pe, \[Theta]2, \[Lambda], \[Psi]1, \[Psi]2, \[Psi]3}, PositiveReals][[1]]) // N` will give some values of the variables/parameters that satisfy the equation.

Comment: It seems to be a complicated transcendental equation, so I wonder, how it can be done by hand really easily?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The unknown is the "L" in the equation, since I tried to solve it with Solve[eq1,L,Reals].

For instance, the solution is:

(θ2 λ ψ1 + ψ2 - E^(1/2 Pe (-L ψ2 + L (ψ2 + ψ3))) θ2 ψ2 - ψ3 + E^(1/2 Pe (-L ψ3 + L (ψ2 + ψ3))) θ2 ψ3) == 0. Then applying the Ln to both sides, it gives:

L=(2/Pe ψ2)ln(θ2(ψ3-ψ1)/(2θ1+ψ3))

The problem is that there is something wrong with my code in the sense that I can't take this answer out of the equation since Mathematica doesn't solve the equation fo L.

Comment: There is no $\theta 1$ in the expression yet your proposed answer includes this variable.

Comment: Hello Josh.  θ1 is the grouping of some variables due to physical properties.

Comment: This is the right way to notify the users in the comments @ and then start typing the user's name. For example @josh will now receive a notification and see that you wrote a reply. Now, back to the OP, may I suggest that you give as much context as possible? You have one equation, you say that the unknown is `L` so what are the other stuff? Parameters? Real ones? And what is `θ1`? If you give more input, maybe we can come up with something.